# On mobile; comment menu has items of varying size, and rotating the phone changes them

Tags: bug, user-interface, design, safari

For some reason just one of my comment notifications is larger than the rest:

[image]

If I rotate the phone from portrait to landscape nothing much changes:

[image]

But oddly, when I rotate it back, everything in the menu is now larger:

[image]

It's not an impediment to use/ everything seems to function normally..

iOS 15.2/iPhone 12 mini/Safari

Comment: Based on your first screenshot, you're using Safari right?

Comment: Correct, apologies for the omission!

Comment: Yeah, it’s been like this for a loooooong time.